# Adding a virtual directory pointing to Azure Cloud Files for Cloud Service via configuration file

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services, azure-storage-files

My work have recently launched a new, always-online, cloud service that has a number of shared resources (learning content) that needs to be available to both the staging environment and production.

We have chose to host these files on an Azure Cloud Files storage device and map the drive on 'Application_start', however, currently we need to manually map the virtual directory to the appropriate location in staging, before swapping with the production environment. This is not ideal as should the virtual machine (VM) be restarted at all, the original, uploaded configuration is used and the virtual directories we added are removed, leaving our content unusable.

Virtual directories appear to be  pre-configurable via the 'ServiceDefinition.csdef' file, however I cannot set the 'physicalDirectory' attribute to the Cloud Files storage device as this is not available on my local device and prevent publishing from proceeding. I fear using configuration transformations will also suffer the same fate.

Previously, I have looked in the use of the LocalStorage feature of the Cloud Service, but this appears to be even more volatile and non-shareable between the set-ups.

Is there a more appropriate storage solution we can look into that will suit our set-up.

Many thanks.

EDIT:
Just a quick example of what I have for the current Virtual Directory set-up in ServiceConfiguration.csdef:

```
    <VirtualDirectory name="media" physicalDirectory="\\drive.file.core.windows.net\media\courseware" />
    <VirtualDirectory name="app_data" physicalDirectory="\\drive.file.core.windows.net\app_name\app_data" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by 'Azure file storage device' you mean 'Azure file service/storage'.

Have you tried to mount share the storage on Web role start, alternatively you can use [net use](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx) (step 4) when your web role starts.

Answer (score 0):

Jack, you need persistent the credential (e.g. your storage account and key) so that your connection to Azure File Storage won't lost during reboot.

Are you using Azure PaaS Role, if that's case, you need to ensure that your code can connect automatically whether the system has started a fresh instance, or if your instance has just been restart.

Please refer to the post below for details.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/27/persisting-connections-to-microsoft-azure-files.aspx